# RXBleConnection keep dropping after connection established (Status 19)

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, rxandroidble

I'm developing an application to pair with two kind of sensors with the app and also these sensors are pairing with each other, we developed our custom bluetooth communication protocol. The connection is working great usually, but there are still some errors that I'm having hard time to fix it.

Sensor 1 paring alone is working great, but every time I'm pairing both of them, then i close the app, pair it again with first sensor, I got disconnected with status 19 just after the connection is established, after I try again one or two times the connection will be established properly. I was thinking that was a problem with Gatt refresh, but I already tried one solution found here and I keep reproducing this error every time.

```
 fun connectToDevice(device: BraincareDevice, pairColor: Int) {
    BleLogHelper.writeLog("Connecting to ${device.name}")
    isConnecting = true
    val deviceType = if (device is Sensor) DeviceType.SENSOR else DeviceType.DONGLE
    if (deviceType == DeviceType.SENSOR) {
        sensorConnectionSubscription?.dispose()
    } else {
        dongleConnectionSubscription?.dispose()
    }


    val connectionSubscription = device.device.establishConnection(false)
            .flatMapSingle { connection ->

                if (device is Sensor) {
                    sensorConnection = connection
                    connectedSensor = device
                } else if (device is Dongle) {
                    dongleConnection = connection
                    connectedDongle = device
                }

                connection.queue(CustomRefresh())
                        ?.observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        ?.doOnComplete{
                            BleLogHelper.writeLog("GATT REFRESHED")
                        }
                        ?.subscribe ({
                            BleLogHelper.writeLog("GATT REFRESHED")
                        },{
                            BleLogHelper.writeLog("FAIL REFRESHING GATT")
                        })

                BleLogHelper.writeLog("Send Request Connection Command $deviceType")
                val command = BraincareBluetoothCommandProtocol.createRequestConnectionCommandFrame(deviceType)
                connection.writeCharacteristic(BraincareBluetoothProtocol.rxCharacteristicUUID, command)
            }
            .delay(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .subscribe({
                BleLogHelper.writeLog("Connection Established ${device.type}")
                val iscon= this.isConnecting
                startBlinkingDeviceLed(deviceType, pairColor)
                connectionFlowListeners.forEach { it.onConnectionEstablished(device) }
            }, {
                BleLogHelper.writeError("Connection Lost ${device.type}", it)
                BleLogHelper.writeError("Retrying...", it)
                val iscon= this.isConnecting
                if (isMonitoring || isConnecting || deviceType == DeviceType.DONGLE){
                    connectionStateListeners.forEach {
                        if (deviceType == DeviceType.SENSOR) {
                            sensorNotificationSubscription?.dispose()
                            sensorRssiSubscription?.dispose()
                            blinkingDeviceLedsSubscription?.dispose()
                            disconnectFromDevice(DeviceType.SENSOR)
                        } else {
                            dongleRssiSubscription?.dispose()
                            disconnectFromDevice(DeviceType.DONGLE)
                        }
                        isConnecting = false
                        it.onConnectionLost(device)
                    }
                }else{
                    reconnectToDevice(device, pairColor)
                }
            })

    if (deviceType == DeviceType.SENSOR) {
        sensorConnectionSubscription = connectionSubscription
    } else {
        dongleConnectionSubscription = connectionSubscription
    }
}
```

The exception is firing just after connection.writeCharacteristic(BraincareBluetoothProtocol.rxCharacteristicUUID, command)

Log error:

```
2019-05-21 10:54:11.816 11797-11889/io.b4c.brain4care.debug E/BLEBC: 21/05/2019 10:54:11.810 - Connection Lost SENSOR
com.polidea.rxandroidble2.exceptions.BleDisconnectedException: Disconnected from D4:57:4F:53:44:E7 with status 19 (UNKNOWN)
    at com.polidea.rxandroidble2.internal.connection.RxBleGattCallback$2.onConnectionStateChange(RxBleGattCallback.java:77)
    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt$1$4.run(BluetoothGatt.java:268)
    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt.runOrQueueCallback(BluetoothGatt.java:789)
    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt.-wrap0(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt$1.onClientConnectionState(BluetoothGatt.java:264)
    at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGattCallback$Stub.onTransact(IBluetoothGattCallback.java:70)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:682)
```

Answer (score 0):

`status=19` is `GATT_CONN_TERMINATE_PEER_USER`. This library since version `1.8.1` lists the reason properly. It is always advised to use the newest available version of basically any library as they bring improvements over time.

There is no clear question in the post. With the provided information it is not possible to tell more than the above — the peripheral you use disconnects from the app. Why this happens is up to your peripheral and you can possibly find an answer in the documentation.

Bear in mind that newer Android versions do not allow concurrent pairing procedures to more than one BLE device at a time. Pairing of two devices should be performed sequentially i.e.

1. Peripheral A starts pairing
2. Peripheral A finishes pairing
3. Peripheral B starts pairing
4. Peripheral B finishes pairing

Peripherals may be connected at the same time but only a single pairing procedure may be held at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the help Dariusz! I don't know if it is concurrent pairing problem because they work great at first pairing, the problem happens after I disconnect them closing the app and then pair again, so I was thiking that there was some caching connection problem. Maybe is some problem with our sensors, we pair both with the app, and them their pair with each other, so one sensor is taking the role as slave and master at the same time, maybe there is some flaw on this connection

Comment: While we're here, can i make one more question? When both sensor are paired, we're losing tons of data, we can see a huge loss of performance. I couldn't find any issue on Android side handling two connections at same time, the sensor A works great paired alone with app, but when I'm pairing sensor B, that also is pairing itself with sensor A, the the package lost is awful, it's weird because the sensor B isn't sending any data, just receiving them. You know if there is some Android limitation? we developed the blutooth protocol for the sensors, so maybe the problem is there.

Comment: It is natural that if you have a resource (a radio) and it gets shared a part for every party involved is reduced. BLE communication is always two-way even if application data is sent only one way, there are responses/ACK after all. If you have three devices connected to each other at the same time things may happen — implementation flaw in a single one will impact all others.

Comment: What do you mean with packet loss? At least for notifications, Android doesn't drop them.

Comment: The sensor is sending that with a sequential number, that being said, when both sensors are connected we can see that a lot of points are not being processed. I just found an clue, I was testing it on a Samsung Tablet SM-T820, and now I just tested on my Xiaomi A2 and works fine